# Batch Prepared Statements in DB2/Java - how to include queued data in SELECTs

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement

I'm working on a Java program that inserts and updates data in a DB2 database. For performance reasons, I'm trying to use prepared statements to queue the data and submit the changes all at once. However, I think I've run into a conceptual block - a number of decisions the program makes are based on data that is both already in the database and queued up in the prepared statements. It seems that standard SELECTs can only see the data that is committed in the database and not the data in the queue.

Am I "doomed" to be forced to commit my changes as I make them in order for the SELECTs to see them, or is there a way that a SELECT query (or something like it) can account for both the data already in the database and the data to be executed in the prepared statements?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Where exactly is the queued data?

Comment: "Queued" in the sense that I've set parameters for a particular record and issued an addBatch() to queue it for processing when I issue an executeBatch(). Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you show you SELECT statement(s) and the Java processing of those rows to make your decision?  I'm wondering if there is a way for the SELECT to perform the "decision" function.  If I can see it, preferably with an explanation of the business rules involved, I might see a way to do it.

Comment: The exact code spans a few methods, but I can give you an idea of the problem through steps. Assume that table X already has some data in it:

 1. Prepare INSERT Statement for table X.
 2. Set parameters
 3. Add to Batch.
 4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 a few times.
 5. SELECT from table X.

Note that the executeBatch method has not yet been called. What I need to happen is that when the SELECT is executed, data from both Table X and the queued batch of INSERTs is returned. My gut hunch is that the queued data cannot be available until the batch is executed, which precludes the use of batching.

Comment: If you can find a prescient database, capable of predicting what you are going to insert before you actually insert it, let us all know.  Please.  ;-)  But could your store the relevant data and manually work that into your SELECT results?  Sure, why not?

Comment: The solution I've used, when possible, has been to maintain a hashmap with the original data plus the data to be inserted while queuing up the batch and querying the dictionary rather than the table. Or forgoing the batch and using executeUpdate, which hurts performance. Ah well, I was hoping...